# Is there a way to get the IP address of the interface on the other end of a wireguard tunnel?

Tags: ip-address, wireguard

Server 1 is the Wireguard server (listening). Its Wireguard interface `wg0` interface IP is 10.100.100.1.

Server 2 is a Wireguard client connecting via the Internet to server 1. Its Wireguard interface gets the IP address 10.100.100.2.

Is there any way, from server 2, to programmatically determine the IP address of the interface on server 1? i.e. from server 2, I want to programmatically get the value `10.100.100.1`.

EDIT: Worth noting that both ends of the tunnel are running Linux, so no need to worry about Windows here.

This is relevant to me because I am writing some scripts on the client end that setup some complex routing and NAT rules, and I need to know the IP address that packets from the server will arrive into the client from via the Wireguard tunnel. In other words, I need to do things to packets coming from `10.100.100.1`. I want to do this programmatically because I want to replicate this setup and I do not like the idea of hardcoding the tunnel host interface IP address in my scripts.

I do not want to simply match on packets coming into the client's `wg0` because there's the possibility of packets with other source IPs coming in based on my advanced routing setup. For example, packets may come in from another client machine at `10.100.100.3` via the tunnel. In other words, packets originating from the tunnel server itself need to be treated differently than packets routed into the tunnel from the server.

Answer (score 0):

`coredns` has a plugin: [wgsd](https://coredns.io/explugins/wgsd/)

---

> wgsd serves WireGuard peer information via DNS-SD (RFC6763) semantics.
> This enables dynamic discovery of WireGuard endpoint addressing (both
> IP address and port number) with the added benefit of NAT-to-NAT
> WireGuard connectivity where UDP hole punching is supported.

---

- `coredns` runs perfectly in a rootless read-only `podman` container as an unprivileged user. There is also no shell in the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/coredns/coredns). I have `coredns` listening on a `wireguard` interface.
- use `slirp4netns` as the network in `podman run` to log the correct source ip's in rootless `podman`.